# Rails routing get and match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

When I'm generating controller with methods in routes I have something like this:

```
get "vehicle_manufacturers/show"
```

Is it a good practice that after that I will write such code:

```
match 'vehicle_manufacturers/:id/' => 'vehicle_manufacturers#show', :as => :vehiclemanufacturers
```

Or, is there another way of writing this code so that will work properly?

Comment: You shouldn't have a route called `"vehicle_manufacturers/show"`, that doesn't make sense. If you're trying to show an *index* of all manufacturers, your route should read `get "vehicle_manufacturers" => "vehicle_manufacturers#index"` (or, far better, use `resources` as described below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best practice to follow [Rails conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for naming and routing to your actions. This lets you say:

```
resources :vehicle_manufacturers
```

This will automatically create routes for `index`, `new`, `create`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `delete` with the appropriate HTTP methods and helper names. Assuming it corresponds to a `VehicleManufacturer` object that conforms to ActiveModel conventions (like ActiveRecord, Mongoid, etc.), `url_for` will automatically Do The Right Thing™, letting you use forms and redirects and such with no extra routing-related work.

It's pretty common that you might only want a subset of these methods. That's fine too:

```
resources :vehicle_manufacturers, :only => [:index, :show]
```

You want to support additional methods outside the normal CRUD methods. Go for it:

```
resources :vehicle_manufacturers, :only => [:index, :show] do
  get :stock_price, :on => :member
end
```

This would add a route named `stock_price_vehicle_manufacturer` mapping to `/vehicle_manufacturers/:id/stock_price`. Although, strictly speaking, I might consider a stock price to be a sub-resource...

The point is, try to use resources as the basis of your routing. It makes everything easier.

Comment: but if i write resources :vehicle_manufacturers, :only => [:index, :show]  how could i assign named route? :as =>

Comment: and also if i haven't in controller default action, only my how then to do?

Comment: The best advice I can give is: first, read the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html); second, try something and check `rake routes` to see what it did. Repeat until you're happy.

Comment: i do this well, and it makes me happy, but i don't know if it is in rails-way